# Данные MIME в формат

Tags: php, mime

Существует ли встроенная функция в php или что либо подобное, для того, чтобы зная MIME файла - вывести формат. К примеру:

```
image/gif -> gif
image/jpeg - jpg
```

и т.п.

P.S. Можно конечно использовать регулярные выражения, но может ещё можно как-то иначе?

Comment: Посмотрите [Fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.fileinfo.php) или функционал [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php) если речь про изображения.

Answer (score 0):

Все ожидания о лёгком решении, разбиваются о суровую реальность:
Какое расширение выбрать, например, для `application/octet-stream`?

Разве что собрать массив `mime -> ext`.